# How to save Sprite objects to file in cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, sprite

How can I serialize and de-serialize Sprite objects in Cocos2dx (efficiently preferred)?
The main purpose of it for me is that I want to save my current game state. I have several game objects with related Sprites on the game scene. So I need somehow to store these objects into the file and restore them back after some time(for example after relaunch application).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to save is only the values which indicate the current game state.

Use CCUserDefault(2.x) to do the job, it is a class which used for saving some information.

When you need to restore the game state. Load the values from CCUserDefault and recreate the scene base on them.

Comment: But I have a lot of cocos2d::Sprite objects on my scene. And they can be in random places on the scene(since they are physical objects). And I would like to restore them in exactly same positions.

Comment: Why don't you save the position of every Sprite by getPosition()?

Comment: Basically every Sprite contains PhysicsBody(which also has some different parameters) and also can be placed with different angles. So seems that this is not enough just to store position.

Comment: Just save all of the values which you need to recreate the scene. Including position, rotation, scale and so on.